# Hi can someone help me with refactoring my button functions?

Tags: javascript

Hi can someone help me with refactoring my button functions?

trying to make 1 function that solves the issue for every button but can't figure how to approach with forEach. also I want alert in my html Element if a field is empty

```
const alert = document.querySelector(".alert")
const billAmount = document.querySelector(".input-box-bill-amt")
const button = document.querySelectorAll(".percent-buttons")
const numOfPeople = document.querySelector(".input-box-num-people")
const tip = document.querySelector(".tip-amount")
const total = document.querySelector(".tip-amount-total")
const reset = document.querySelector(".reset")

if(billAmount || numOfPeople = " "){
alert.innerHtml = "Please make sure you fill in every field"
}else{

button[0].addEventListener('click', () => {
        tip.innerHTML = `${((5 / 100) * billAmount.value) / numOfPeople.value}`;
        total.innerHTML = `${(billAmount.value / numOfPeople.value) + (((5 /100) * billAmount.value) / numOfPeople.value)}`
    })

button[1].addEventListener('click', () => {
    
    tip.innerHTML = `${((10 / 100) * billAmount.value) / numOfPeople.value}`;
    total.innerHTML = `${(billAmount.value / numOfPeople.value) + (((10 / 100) * billAmount.value) / numOfPeople.value)}`
})

button[2].addEventListener('click', () => {
    tip.innerHTML = `${((15 / 100) * billAmount.value) / numOfPeople.value}`;
    total.innerHTML = `${(billAmount.value / numOfPeople.value) + (((15 / 100) * billAmount.value) / numOfPeople.value)}`
})

button[3].addEventListener('click', () => {

    tip.innerHTML = `${((25 / 100) * billAmount.value) / numOfPeople.value}`
    total.innerHTML = `${(billAmount.value / numOfPeople.value) + (((25 /100) * billAmount.value) / numOfPeople.value)}`
})

button[4].addEventListener('click', () => {
    
    tip.innerHTML = `${((50 / 100) * billAmount.value) / numOfPeople.value}`
    total.innerHTML = `${(billAmount.value / numOfPeople.value) + (((50 /100) * billAmount.value) / numOfPeople.value)}`
})

reset.addEventListener('click', () => {
    billAmount.value = '';
    custom.value = '';
    numOfPeople.value = '';
    tip.innerHTML = '00.00';
    total.innerHTML = '00.00';
})}
```

Comment: Can you add the html also? Also please mention whether your currecnt code is working as expected or not. If you are looking for a refactor

Comment: thank you for feedback will add it next time,Andreas's answer covers there solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the buttons does the same logic but with different values. You can create a helper method that does this with the percentage as input:

```
const onClick = (percentage) => {
    tip.innerHTML = `${((percentage / 100) * billAmount.value) / numOfPeople.value}`
    total.innerHTML = `${(billAmount.value / numOfPeople.value) + (((percentage/100) * billAmount.value) / numOfPeople.value)}`
}
```

You can then create an array for the percentages the different buttons use:

```
const percentages = [5, 10, 15, 25, 50]
```

and then you can iterate each button to set the onclicks:

```
button.forEach((button, index) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
      onClick(percentages[index])
  })
})
```